# Stuck in multiline edit mode when importing module in Node.js REPL

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm on node v7.5.0. I run `node` and then:

```
> import moment from 'moment';
... moment();
...
```

I get stuck in multiline mode as you can see. How do I use `import` in Node REPL?

Answer (score 1):

Node does not support the module import/export syntax yet. You will have to stick with this for now:

```
moment = require('moment')
```